# Old black&white sci-fi movie; two kids find a flying saucer

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, flying-saucer

Looking for a movie I saw as a kid which scared the bageebuz out of me. I think it was black and white. Story is:

This flying saucer lands in a park but has the ability to be invisible. These 2 kids, boy & girl, are walking around the park. The aliens see them (they look like us, not creepy aliens) and make the ship visible. The 2 kids are "hey, looky there, there's a flying saucer, let's find the door and look inside". They are greeted by two aliens (men I think) and they are nice enough, "hey, come inside, look around, check this out, hey kids want some candy".

So the kids are checking out the spaceship, and they start asking questions. The aliens are "sure, we’ll tell you all about our technology, here, work on these difficult math equations..." Meanwhile the ship has turned invisible. The longer the kids are gone, the parents wonder. So the kids are learning a lot but soon it's dinnertime and the kids have got to go: "ok open the door, we gotta go home". But the aliens say, "well sorry kids, you've already learned too much, your kind can't handle the things you've learned, so you gotta stay with us".

So they get locked in a cell for the night. The parents are freaking out and a search begins of the park. So the kids spend some time aboard the flying saucer with the really nice aliens. During the day they learn calculus, algebra, trig, and alien technology (somehow the aliens make it really fun to learn). Eventually the kids start to wonder what the alien agenda is and ask their hosts when they can go home, and without a good straight answer they become suspicious. By now the search has escalated to dynamic proportions.

The kids hear the aliens talking and the gist is, the reason the aliens are teaching them so much is because where they are from children’s brains are a delicacy and the more knowledge they can shove in there the better they taste. "Oh no they want to eat our brains." So the children stop learning anything and try to be more dumb (so they won't taste so good). Eventually they discover a mass in the park national guard shows up. They beat on the door, "we know you're in there, open up", and the kids escape. Happy ending: the aliens are like "you're not ready for our technology" and take off. The end.

Been wondering about this for a while. I was glued to the TV when I saw it as a kid. It has scared me for life; I can never forget this movie.

Comment: When were you a kid?  i.e. when did you see this?

Comment: Must have been late 70s we had 4 channels 2denver (the cannel i saw it on 5/6 cbs 7 pbs 10 nbc12 abc channel 2 played sci fi movies on the weekend b&w alien godzilla stuff good stuff

Comment: Im sure the film was much older

Comment: Gamera vs. Guiron; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tJhPiQt-ko - Aliens kidnap kids so they can eat their brains...

Comment: Nope not it nice try though. Wasnt a godzilla gamuron movie dont think it was jap at all. Just a cheezy old b sci fi flick (which is why its so hard to figure out) was low low budget most of the film was in the flying saucer which was constructed of cardboard boxes lights switches maybe an old tv or 2. In the days of rockets you could see the wires. The story plot was hansel & gretal and the end was like the day the earth stood still. Pretty sure it was black n white. Definately a b movie, saw it via antenna, they never played good mainstream theater stuff

Comment: Furthermore the only parts filmed outside the flying saucer were the begining filmed in the park and some flashes of the parents and search of the park. And the end had to be most expensive with cars and police and maybe a tank or cannon or something. Such a low budget movie i could consider making it myself (just need lots of cardboard fridge boxes)